# Get Stored Procedure Output DataSet from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a stored procedure which accepts a single input parameter and returns a data set. I want to invoke this stored procedure from my ADF Pipeline and with the stored proc data, I want to call another proc with whose result I want to do further processing.

I tried with the `Stored Procedure Activity` but it's output doesn't contain the actual data set:

```
{
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (Australia East)",
    "executionDuration": 0,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Also, I tried with `LookUp Activity`but it's result only contains the first row of the resultant data set:

```
{
    "firstRow": {
        "CountryID": 1411,
        "CountryName": "Maldives",
        "PresidentName": "XXXX"
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (Australia East)",
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "DIUHours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    }
}
```

My main intention behind using ADF is to reduce the huge amount of time taken otherwise by an existing API (.Net Core) for the same steps. What else can be done? Should I consider any other Azure Service(s)?

Comment: The Stored Proc activity does not return the resultsets from procs.  The Script activity does but is limited to 5,000 rows / 2MB, as is the Lookup activity if you uncheck the First row only option.

Comment: @wBob fair enough, but what if my SP returns more than 5000 rows of code?

Comment: You might need to rethink the design.  The limits are in place for a reason and if you’re thinking of looping through 10,000 things in ADF then you should know you pay per activity.  Why not pass this all off to the database?  Just have one Stored Proc activity that sets all this off in the db.

Comment: @wBob thanks for your suggestion, let me re-consider the design

Comment: I would try and draw out logically what you want to do without using ADF tasks, like you’ve got a source API, you want to land the data somewhere, you want to process it somehow.  That would be really useful I think.  Maybe then map ADF or db activities to that.